# An $L^1$ estimates related to Fejer Kernels

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, integral-inequality

Suppose that
$$
V_{n}(x)=(1+e(nx)+e(-nx))K_{n}(x),
$$
where $e(x)=\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}x}$, and $K_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{\sin^{2}(n\pi x)}{\sin^{2}(\pi x)}$.
Now I want to estimates:
$$
\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\left|V_{n}'(x)\right|\mathrm{d}x\le Cn,
$$
where $C$ is independent of $n$, Any suggestions?

---

What I've tried some result till now:

$$
\begin{aligned}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\left|V_{n}'(x)\right|\mathrm{d} x & \le\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\left|(1+e(nx)+e(-nx))'K_{n}(x)\right|\mathrm{d} x+\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\left|(1+e(nx)+e(-nx))K_{n}'(x)\right|\mathrm{d} x\\
 & \lesssim\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}n\left|K_{n}(x)\right|\mathrm{d} x+\int_{0}^{1/2}\left|K_{n}'(x)\right|\mathrm{d} x\\
 & \lesssim n\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}C_{K}\mathrm{d} x+\int_{0}^{2\pi/n}\left|K_{n}'(x)\right|\mathrm{d} x+\int_{2\pi/n}^{1/2}\left|K_{n}'(x)\right|\mathrm{d} x\\
 & \lesssim Cn+\int_{0}^{2\pi/n}cn^{2}\mathrm{d} x+\int_{2\pi/n}^{1/2}\left|K_{n}'(x)\right|\mathrm{d} x\\
 & \lesssim Cn+\int_{2\pi/n}^{1/2}\left|K_{n}'(x)\right|\mathrm{d} x
\end{aligned}
$$

how to estimate $\int_{2\pi/n}^{1/2}\left|K_{n}'(x)\right|\mathrm{d} x$?

---

I've checked Fourier Analysis from stein, p. 115-116.
the last term can be controlled well. So I'll leave this without re-editting..

Comment: You want to show $\vert (1+e(nx)+e(-nx))\vert$ for all $x$ and $\vert K_n(x)\vert \leq C$ for $\vert x\vert \leq 1/2$. For the derivatives you pick up an additional factor of $n$ which implies your result.

Comment: @Severin Schraven: I add some result from your hint, how to tackle the term $|K_n'|$ in the last integral?.

Comment: You can do a direct computation and then use Taylor to see that the there is a cancellation in the numerator which gives you the desired estimate.